# Graphql Conditional Query

Tags: php, graphql

How can I conditionally use graphql such that when address is given it returns Account and when it isn't it retunrs the authenticated user?
accountByAddress(address: String! @where(operator: "like")): [Account!]! @all

Answer (score 0):

you can use @skip or @auth to skip or return authenticated user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).